# SQL Server - Excluding records from a view if two certain fields are both null

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I'm writing a view in SQL Server and I need the results filtered so that if two particular fields on a record have null values then that record is excluded.

As an example a table `Customer` has fields `Code, Name, Address, Payment, Payment_Date`.

If both `Payment` & `Payment_Date` are null then exclude the record from the result set, however if just one is null (or any other field) then it's fine to return the record.

Is this functionality possible in SQL Server?? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   other_conditions
        …
        AND (payment IS NOT NULL OR payment_date IS NOT NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

Take the coalesceof the two fields, and check that value for null

```
select * from yourtable where coalesce(field1, field2, field3, etc, etc,) is not null
```

this is somewhat easier on the eyes than a string of OR clauses (imho)

Comment: @Lasse - No. Also the expressions need to be compatible datatypes. Which will not be the case if `Payment` is decimal and `Payment_Date` date. (but will be if float and datetime!)

Comment: @Lasse: no, but it's very improbable that the indexes would be ever used for filtering this.

Comment: @Martin - very good point on compatible datatypes -- didn't see that requirement in the OP until I looked again.  As for `coalesce` being sargable or not, I would be surprised if the compiler didn't expand the `coalesce` into a `case` or some such thing, but even if it did, I suspect @quassnoi is correct that the indexes would not likely be selected.

Comment: @Ralph - It does get expanded to `CASE` but `CASE` isn't sargable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the where clause, simply turn it around and use an OR instead:

```
WHERE
(
  PAYMENT IS NOT NULL
  OR
  PAYMENT_DATE IS NOT NULL
)
AND
  -- ...rest of where clause here...
```